Is it possible to not get NaN for the first value of pct_change()?
My DataFrame is:
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [20, 30, 2, 5, 10]
    }
)

Expected output is pct_change() of a:
    a  pct_change
0  20  -50.000000
1  30   50.000000
2   2  -93.333333
3   5  150.000000
4  10  100.000000

I want to compare df.a.iloc[0] with 40 for the first value of pct_change. If I use df['pct_change'] = df.a.pct_change().mul(100), the first value is NaN.
My Attempt:
def percent(a, b):
    result = ((a - b) / b) * 100
    return result.round(2)

df.loc[df.index[0], 'pct_change'] = percent(df.a.iloc[0], 40)

Is there a better/more efficient way?

You can use the fill_value keyword argument in pct_change.
The pct_change documentation says:

Additional keyword arguments are passed into DataFrame.shift or Series.shift.

and Series.shift accepts a fill_value argument to fill missing rows.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [20, 30, 2, 5, 10]})

df["pct_change"] = df["a"].pct_change(fill_value=40).mul(100)

print(df)

Output:
    a  pct_change
0  20  -50.000000
1  30   50.000000
2   2  -93.333333
3   5  150.000000
4  10  100.000000


One method that I have found really helpful is using apply method along with lambda. It checks the index and performs accordingly. You can also do this across the DataFrame with no issue.
So it would look something like this:
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [20, 30, 2, 5, 10]
})

# Define a function to calculate the percentage change
def percent_change(row):
    # Check if it's the first row
    if row.name == 0:
        # Compare with 40 for the first value
        return ((row - 40) / 40) * 100
    else:
        # For subsequent rows, use the standard pct_change() method
        return row.pct_change() * 100

# Apply the function to the 'a' column
df['pct_change'] = df['a'].apply(percent_change)

print(df)

Pay attention to the if row.name == 0: as well, that defines it to compare it with the first value.
